# What is a good way to set a value on a table that is frequently accessed

Tags: sql, sql-server

There  is a table "Message" with millions of entries in it. There are lots of queries and updates/inserts to that table.It also has some indexes on it.

Frequently when we change the schema of that table we run into performance issues.

Now we have to set all values of a bit column "IsSynchronized" to 0.

What would be the safest way to do that? I can think of

- drop the column an create it again
- have a process that updates the values in batches

Comment: "Frequently when we change the schema of that table" That right there is a sign of a potential design problem. schema changes should not be frequent.

Comment: I would for sure use an UPDATE. Wouldn't even *think* about the other way :-)

Comment: Drop the column and create it again as not null with a default will be potentially quickest - these are both metadata only operations if you are on enterprise edition and 2012+. It will have to acquire a short lived `SCH-M` lock on the table though which can cause blocking until it gets it.

Comment: I would go the update route personally. Then if you need to carry out the task again it's easy to script or repeat and monitor. Just check for stats going stale or indexes on the column maybe.